# SSL Certificates for HERE URL's Expiring soon

Tags: javascript, here-api

We are using SSL certificates for the below URL's which are going to expire soon.

*.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
geocoder.ls.hereapi.com

Any idea on when the certificates would be updated for these URL's?

Answer (score 0):

HERE APIs are providing always the latest certificates, there is no separate repository, they can be downloaded from.

Via a browser call certificate information can be accessed. Below you can see an example how this can be done.

1.
[image]

2. Click "More Information"

[image]

3. Click "View Certificates", details become visible and can be downloaded.
   [image]